# Printing ZPL (Zebra Programming language) file via Powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, zpl

I wrote a Powershell script that asks questions, takes the user's input, plugs those variables in a label created in ZPL, then print it out via `Out-Printer`. Everything seems to work fine except the label that prints has incorrect spacing or missing data.

Originally I had the script create a .txt file that held the label in ZPL format. Checking the label all the data was correct. When I would print the .txt file from Notepad using the same printer (Driver was set to Generic/ Plain text). The label would be perfect.

I also tried switching the printing method to the WMI variant. It would do the same formatting issues and missing data, but now in different spots.

It almost seems Powershell is formatting the data before it prints.

Here is the current code I have with some data censored for privacy concerns.

```
$i = 0
$global:counter = $i + 1
$AllPrinters = gwmi win32_printer -computername $env:computername
$DefaultPrinterString = $AllPrinters | where {$_.Default -eq $true}
$DefaultPrinter = [regex]::match($DefaultPrinterString, '\"([^\"]+)\"').Groups[1].Value

Write-Host "========== Print Company Labels =========="
Write-Host "Question will be on the left, type in answer and hit ENTER"

$location = Read-Host "Which location? (LOC1 or LOC2)"
$pro = Read-Host "What is the Pro#?"
$quote = Read-Host "What is the quote number?"
$pallet = Read-Host "How many pallets are there?"
$printer = Read-Host "What printer do you want?"

While ($global:counter -le $pallet)
{

$printcode = "^XA^MCY^XZ^XA^SZ2^MMT^MTT~JSN^LT0^MD0^MNY^PR5^PON^PMN^CI0^LRN
^FT300,1300^A0B,350,160^FDPRO: $pro^FS
^FT480,1300^A0B,175,150^FD$location^FS
^FT480,1300^A0B,175,150^FD$location^FS
^FT480,900^A0B,175,100^FDQuote: $quote^FS
^FT800,1300^A0B,350,225^FDPallet $global:counter of $pallet^FS
^PQ01~*QUANT,04~,0,~*COPIES,04~,N^MCY^XZ"

(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter($printer)
$printcode | Out-Printer
Start-Sleep 1
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter($DefaultPrinter)

$global:counter++
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the output in the text file? Have you looked for any hidden characters in the text file?

Comment: I uploaded 2 pictures to my Google Albums:
<br>
goo.gl/photos/QQoKuX6Fm2uzMWBB9
<br>
Add "https:" to the front, SE doesn;t allow short links and thats all google provides
<br>
Picture on the left is printed from Notepad using the file output from the powershell script and the same printer. Picture on the right is the direct output from the powershell script for the same label. The direct output from Powershell is missing the quote section. The odd part is that I'm using the same data.

Comment: Try the [PsZebra](https://github.com/craibuc/PsZebra) PowerShell module.