# ZPL/Powershell Printing Issue - M of N Documents Processing

Tags: powershell, printing, zpl

I had a very similar situation to the following post: [Another StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39856130/14502211)

However, after running the PS script, inputting the data, and letting it roll, I get a window that pops up saying "Printing page # of document" where '#' begins counting - I've let it hit 70+ before I cancel the print request, as I do not want to waste labels.

Here is my code:

```
$AllPrinters = gwmi win32_printer -computername $env:computername
$DefaultPrinterString = $AllPrinters | where {$_.Default -eq $true}
$DefaultPrinter = [regex]::match($DefaultPrinterString, '\"([^\"]+)\"').Groups[1].Value
$targetPrinter = "PDC CERTIS B2-20"

$fn = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter patient first name: "
$ln = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter patient last name: "
$dob = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter patient DOB (use mm/dd/yyyy as format): "
$mrn = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter patient record number: "

$pt = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    MedRecNum = $mrn
    FirstName = $fn
    LastName = $ln
    DOB = $dob
}

$print_code = "^XA
^FO100,200^ADR,48,30^FDLast Name: " + ($pt.LastName) + "^FS
^FO20,200^ADR,48,30^FDFirst Name: " + ($pt.FirstName) + "^FS
^FO100,900^ADR,48,30^FDDOB: " + ($pt.DOB) + "^FS
^FO50,1600^BY3^B3R,N,100,Y,N^FD" + ($pt.MedRecNum) + "^FS
^PQ1^MCY
^XZ"

$print_code | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\ezWrist.zpl #This was to check if the print code above wrote to file
#I've also tried using Get-Content -Path and piping it to Out-Printer as the whole file --- no such luck

(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter($targetPrinter)
$print_code | Out-Printer
Start-Sleep 1
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter($DefaultPrinter)</code>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/ problem?

Comment: Sorry, new to this Stack Overflow - it wont just print the label. If I go into the printer properties, I can send a file directly to the printer, and sending a .zpl file will print successfully, but sending the file to the printer via PS, it attempts to print what it thinks is a multipage document.

Comment: Double check your Zebra Programming Language syntax with the version install on the printer.  It sounds like you are missing the command to let the printer know that the end of the print job was reached.